# How is margin-top and margin-bottom getting added

Tags: css, css-float

I am building my first website after reading through CSS and HTML.I was able to bring the header on my index page with nav bar and the brand. For the brand, I aligned it in the center using the margin-top property and set the navigation links using float property. However, when I inspect the `ul` element using firefox,

1. I see a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of `16 px` each which I do not have a clue on how its getting added.
2. Is aligning the brand using the `margin-top` property the right way to center align?
3. Why is the `ul` element not taking the entire height of `44 px` set for the header.

I am adding the plunker url for more details: http://plnkr.co/edit/RjQtIR?p=preview

Code for more details:

```
<header class="main-header">
        <nav class="top-bar clearfix">
            <span class="brand">Money Plant Services</span>
            <section class="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav-items">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
    </header>

CSS:

.main-header{
  width: 100%;
  height:44px;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
}

.brand{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-menu{
  float:right;
}

.nav-items{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-items li{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li > a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ul has a default margin so you can remove that by adding....

```
 <ul style="margin:0px">
```

Also margins are different from browser to browser so its worth checking out info online about it or test it for yourself using inspect element.

When aligning horixontally there are many ways to do it...

you could use the text-align method or the margin auto method or the custom padding way.(there are also other ways).

Example:

```
<div style="width:400px;height:20px;text-align:center;">
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;">
</div></div>
```

Example:

```
<div style="width:400px;height:20px;">
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
</div></div>
```

Vertical align is a bit harder but can be done with table cells (there are also other methods).

The right way to align is either using the text-align property or using auto margins as said by the w3c validation service.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will helps you. Just replace the below code with yours it will works...

CSS:

```
.nav-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top:8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```